# Instantiation of a class doesn't work (Chisel/Scala)

Tags: scala, chisel

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: must be inside Builder context
```

issue when I write this on the terminal : sbt run

This is my code:

```scala
import chisel3._

class combinedTausworthe extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {})
  val seed1 = RegInit(322769304.U(32.W))
  val seed2 = RegInit(424235419.U(32.W))
  val seed3 = RegInit(212119443.U(32.W))
  var result = 0.U

  var b = ((seed1 << 13)(31, 0) ^ seed1)
  seed1 := ((seed1 & 4294967294L.U) << 12)(31, 0) ^ b
  b := ((seed2 << 2)(31, 0) ^ seed2) >> 25
  seed2 := ((seed2 & 4294967294L.U) << 4)(31, 0) ^ b
  b := ((seed3 << 3)(31, 0) ^ seed3) >> 11
  seed3 := ((seed3 & 4294967294L.U) << 17)(31, 0) ^ b

  result := (seed1 ^ seed2 ^ seed3)
  println(result)

}

object Main extends App {
  val variable = Module(new combinedTausworthe())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For instantiation of the top of your design, you need to invoke `ChiselStage` or some other entry-point function.

If you wish to compile and dump Verilog, try:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  emitVerilog(new combinedTausworthe) // this was added in v3.5.0
  
  // If you are using a version older than v3.5.0, use the following
  (new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new combinedTausworthe)
}
```

If you wish to just get a `String` that you can print, try the following:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  println(getVerilogString(new combinedTausworthe)) // this was added in v3.5.0
  
  // If you are using a version older than v3.5.0, use the following
  println(chisel3.stage.ChiselStage.emitVerilog(new combinedTausworthe))
}
```

Comment: Hi ! I tried this and there is an error " chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Cannot reassign to read-only combinedTausworthe.b: OpResult[UInt<32>]
"
I don't necessarily need to transform it into Verilog file.

Actually, all I want is to manipulate the "result" variable, and to print() it on the console! And i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Hello! That's a different error that will be hard to answer via comments so if you could ask it in another question that would be helpful. Per wanting to "manipulate the 'result' variable", can you elaborate a little bit on what you mean? What sort of manipulations do you have in mind?

Comment: Well, I wanna do, in the Main, something like io.clock.step(1). So then it's gonna print the "result" variable for each cycle. But for that, I need to instanciate the combinedTauswhore Class.

Comment: Generally you do this using ScalaTest as shown in the chisel-template: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/blob/015e98f904c4fe96990c00d4641ad047ea6de4d6/src/test/scala/gcd/GCDSpec.scala

Comment: That being said, you can use `chiseltest.RawTester.test` as the entry point that will enable you to test the result, see the following example: https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/blob/bca685a668b044b186d6a71525eebb096e5ffb9d/src/test/scala/chiseltest/tests/NoScalatestTesterTest.scala